# Installing Java using batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to install java using windows batch file,means suppose I have jdk1.7.exe file and I want it to convert in batch file.I am totally new to this topic and I am really not getting what to do..? 
I am not aware of batch programming too.If someone can help will be appreciated. Any suggetions,links,data most welcome.
Thanks..!!

Comment: Why you suppose to do that? IF you already have exe

Comment: start /d "path" file.exe :p

Comment: i want to run a silent install that would not display the gui installer of jdk

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you want is install Java in silent mode.
For that, run `jdk1.7.exe /s`

More information: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml